# Copy form input ONLY when checkbox is checked - React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, react-hook-form

I am trying to have two forms where the second form copies the input from the first one when the checkbox is checked.

I came across this code from React Hook Form Library, however, even when the checkbox is NOT checked, the second form still copies the input from the first one.

I've been trying to fix it but can't find what's wrong with the code.

Here the CSB: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-dew-1pvsw?file=/src/Contact.tsx

[Copy Form Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BK8ra.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making mistake while copying the checkbox value. here is the code update.

```
const Contact = ({
  email,
  email2,
  checked,
  setChecked
}: {
  email: string;
  email2: string;
  checked: boolean;
  setChecked: (checked: boolean) => void;
}) => {
  const { handleSubmit, register, setValue, watch } = useForm({
    defaultValues: { email: email, email2: email2, checky: checked // 1- Add checkbox to form }
  });
  const onSubmit = (values) => console.log(values);
  const watchEmail = watch("email", email);
  const checkbox = watch("checky", checked); // const checkbox = watch("checkbox", email); you're assiging wrong value to checkbox
......
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked. 
How about if the forms are in two separate components? -- 
https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-clarke-9m8bo?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Either you need to use the global store like (React Context API/Redux or any) or you need to lift your state to the parent component.

Comment: @L.Diaz Accept the solution as an answer if it worked for you. It may increase the reach and also help someone else to find the solution.